# Why the boolean is different between if (variable) and if (variable == true)?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the if statement and boolean evaluation in JavaScript.

I create on jsFiddle example of that [click](http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/pJRdn/1/), there's four different functions which evaluates the types in array through the loop.

But let's focus only on function b and c.

```
function b(p) {
    return (p == true);
}

function c(p) {
    if (p) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the console the results are different, for example, -1 and 'Hello' are true to the c, while false in b.

Why that's happens?

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`-1 != true` and `Hello != true` yet both `-1` and `Hello` are truth-y and evaluate to true when cast to a boolean (which is what the if statement does) which is why

```
if('Hello') {
  return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
```

returns true;

Comment: But isn't the `== true` is loosely type check? I mean `'hello' === true` definitely would be false.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just type this in your console `(Boolean('Hello') == true)` vs `('Hello' == true)`. Hopefully that will make sense for you.

Comment: @Volter9: Yes, it's a loose (coercing) test. But [if you read up on how `==` works](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), it's plain why `"hello" == true` is false. For more information, read the answers to the question this duplicates.

Comment: @Volter9: To be clear, the type of coercion done by `==` isn't a simple `Boolean()` conversion. The algorithm used by `==` is quite a bit more complex. Adam's comment shows an example. Best is to understand the underlying algorithm if you want to use `==`.